# Manipulating a mocked Calendar object to return specific days

Tags: junit, powermock, easymock

I'm using a Calendar object to determine whether or not to increase the workload of a system based on current day/hour values. Given that this object uses static methods, I'm using PowerMock to mock the static methods with the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Calendar.class })
```

The code under test is pretty simple (though my logic needs work, I know):

```
public void determineDefaultMaximumScans() throws ParseException{  
parseTime();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

if(dayOfWeek == (Calendar.SATURDAY) || dayOfWeek == (Calendar.SUNDAY)){
        setDefaultMax(calculateNewDefaultMax(getDefaultMax()));
        System.out.println("defaultMax increased by 20%");
    } else {
        if(currentTime.after(afterHoursBegin) && currentTime.before(afterHoursEnd)){
            System.out.println("Not afterhours. Maintaining current maximum.");
            setDefaultMax(defaultMax);
            System.out.println("Current Maximum number of scans: " + getDefaultMax());
        }

    }
}
```

My test case reads as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Test
public void testDetermineMaximumScans() throws ParseException{
    PowerMock.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
    String beginningTime = "18:00";
    String endingTime = "05:00";

    mockAfterHoursBegin = parser.parse(beginningTime);
    mockAfterHoursEnd = parser.parse(endingTime);
    mockCurrentTime = parser.parse(parser.format(new Date()));

    EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andReturn(mockCalendar);
    EasyMock.expect(mockCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)).andReturn(6);


    EasyMock.replay(mocks);
    offHourMaximumCalculator.determineDefaultMaximumScans();
    EasyMock.verify(mocks);
}
```

As of now, all of my attempts to return a specific value result in the following assertion error. Now I vaguely understand why it's returning the default but I do not see why I can't force the value or how to get around this expectation. Mocks in general are still a frustrating mystery to me. What am I missing?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
Calendar.get(7): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Comment: FYI: `Calendar` is a terrible old class, now legacy, supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes such as `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Mocks are fairly simple. But wanting to mock static methods is a big running after complexity. I generally do not recommend to mock something like a Calendar. If you do weird and complex thing with it, just encapsulate in something you can test and mock easily.

And in fact, we pretty much never use `Calendar.getInstance()`. It returns something according to the locale. But it's rare that you don't want a specific calendar i.e. `GregorianCalendar`. So just do `new GregorianCalendar`.

But anyway, add a protected method doing

```
protected Calendar newCalendar() {
    return Calendar.getInstance(); // or new GregorianCalendar()
}
```

will take 2 minutes and then a simple partial mock will do the trick.

Finally, I also don't recommend to use `Calendar`. You have a much nicer API in `java.util.date` in Java 8.

All this said, here is how you should do it. Calendar is a system class, so you need to follow a real specific path which is explained [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System).

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Calendar.class)
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void testDetermineMaximumScans() throws ParseException {
    PowerMock.mockStatic(Calendar.class);

    Calendar calendar = mock(Calendar.class);

    EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andReturn(calendar);
    EasyMock.expect(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)).andReturn(6);

    // really important to replayAll to replay the static expectation
    PowerMock.replayAll(calendar);
    assertThat(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)).isEqualTo(6);

    // and verifyAll is you want to verify that the static call actually happened    
    PowerMock.verifyAll();
  }

}
```